# why it shows 'hypervisor is detected' under Hyper-V requirements, even after removing Hyper-V feature

Tags: device, hyper-v, guard

[image: enter image description hereit shows 'hypervisor is detected' under Hyper-V requirements, even after removing Hyper-V feature]

on an admin command prompt, I run systemifo. and it shows 'hypervisor is detected' under Hyper-V requirements, even after removing Hyper-V feature

Comment: Are you running `systeminfo` on an existing Hyper-V host? Because in that case, `systeminfo` will always say `A hypervisor has been detected`. If not, you can try disabling *Virtualization Technology* in your BIOS - that should disable it for sure

Comment: To know the problem is that I installed Android Studio and when I want to install "intel x86 emulator accelerator (HAXM installer)"
in sdk tools i get this problem"Unable to install Intel® HAXM
HAXM can only be installed on Windows or Mac.
Please file a bug against Android Studio." and when i want to intalled Separated i get this problem "this computer does not support intel virtualization technology (vt-x)"
and when i was looking for solution  i found that i need to enable  Virtualization Technology in your BIOS but nothing worked